# Azure Event Hub metrics on Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-eventhub, azureportal

I've got an Azure function that consumes messages from an Azure Service Bus and publishes messages to an Event Hub for another team to consume regularly. Is there any default/out of the box metrics available on Application Insights/Azure Portal to see if there are messages on the Event Hub that are yet to be consumed by anyone?

Comment: to see if there are messages on the Event Hub that are yet to be consumed  we have add alias data in the Event Hubs Instance. Create an Azure Data Explorer Database and Database.Go to Azure Data Explorer select the Database  and run the query using the database name to view data

Comment: @Sampath What want to be able to see this info on an Azure Workbook

Comment: we able see only number of messages in event and outgoing message and there difference shows the number of message sent in  Azure Workbook . To see message you need to use Azure Data Explorer Clusters/Stream Analytics jobs  and send to other [resource](https://i.imgur.com/UWeeW71.png)